# How to prevent VS Code from opening multiple instances of a same file?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

VS Code someone point me to an existing opened file, other times it create a new instance (of VS Code as well as the file).

Answer (score 25):

By default, VS Code will open a new Editor with the desired file. If you'd like to instead reveal the already open Editor, set workbench.editor.revealIfOpen to true in your User Settings (CMD+k on OSX).

To be concrete, that means adding the following line:

```json
"workbench.editor.revealIfOpen": true,
```

**See Also**: [Visual studio Code - prevent same file opening twice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43135102/2970867)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. After enabling revealIfOpen, using Ctrl+o to open a new file opens it in a second VSCode instance, instead of the original instance. Very frustrating, as I want all open files to be in one instance and I want to work with groups of files and with workspaces in one Windows instance.

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work across instances?

Comment: This only works if `"window.openFilesInNewWindow": "off"`. i.e. you are opening the already opened file in the same window. If vscode is default to opening files in a new window, then the `revealIfOpen` option doesn't work at all.

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU! I Cmd-click source code error messages in my terminal, and it's been driving me nuts that vscode opens the file in whatever pane is focused, instead of focusing on the file already open in another pane. Checking this setting FIXED THIS immediately. Happy!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
  "window.openFilesInNewWindow": "off",
  "window.openFoldersInNewWindow": "off",
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "prompt"
```